# Wix installer - Primary Output From "Project" Releasex64 / Buildx64

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, installation, wix

my project is C++/MFC and i'm converting from VS2010 to VS2012. i'm using Wix 3.7 as an installer. 
in Visual Stduio's installer i could get the Primary Output from a Project from release or debug libraries.
as show in the picture below:
[image]

i have found that i can do the same from the **Build** by adding a reference to the Wix Project, setting the HEAT harvest to "TRUE", and adding a component to the directory i want to add the file:

[image]

how can i do the same for the release?? do i just change to release? so how can you decide if a file needs to be in the installer for the release or is it an installer for debug where you don't need the file.

Comment: i have changed the source of the file to be ..\bin\Debug.x64 and the files from Release to be ..\bin\Release.x64. so now i build the project for Release and after that into Debug and i get the files that i want. you can also use <?if $(var.Configuration) == Debug> do... <?endif?>